# Revert flipping a DIV after clicking another one

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, flip

Take a look a this [link](http://ananiadis.com.gr/index2.php/?page_id=560). If you click on a product it flips and shows some information. You can flip all products at a given time.

I want to be able to only have one flipped product. Every time someone clicks another product, I want the previous one to flip back to its original appearance.

The html:

```
<div class="card effect__EFFECT">
  <div class="card__front">
    <span class="card__text">front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <span class="card__text">back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener( card );
  }

  function clickListener(card) {
    card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
      var c = this.classList;
      c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
    });
  }
})();
```

The CSS:

```
.card.effect__click.flipped .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

Comment: remove flipped class from all cards first , if any card contains then run your current function. write this event in clickListener() function before var C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove 'flipped' class on card on click.

```
      function clickListener(card) {
           card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
               $('.card.effect__click').removeClass('flipped');
               var c = this.classList;
               c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
           });
      }
```

Comment: Yay! It worked. I had to change your $ to jQuery though. But thanks for the quick fix & response. :D