# Revert the effect of flipping a div when clicking elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this [website](http://ananiadis.com.gr/index2.php/pick-me/).

When you click on a product, it flips and shows a description. If you click another product, then the first one you clicked, is flipped and the new one flips too. So far so good.

What I need is that if you click the **same** product, to flip again to its original state.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card effect__EFFECT">
  <div class="card__front">
    <span class="card__text">front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <span class="card__text">back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
(function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener( card );
  }

  function clickListener(card) {
       card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
           jQuery('.card.effect__click').removeClass('flipped');
           var c = this.classList;
           c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
       });
  }
})();
```

**CSS**

```
.card.effect__click.flipped .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes add your code please.

Comment: Just did. Look also at this, if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022455/revert-flipping-a-div-after-clicking-another-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has same issue, the correct code is this:

```
<script>
jQuery('.card.effect__click').click(function() {

if (jQuery(this).hasClass('flipped')){
jQuery(this).removeClass('flipped');
}
else {jQuery(this).addClass('flipped');}

if (jQuery('.card.effect__click').hasClass('flipped')){
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    jQuery('.card.effect__click').removeClass('flipped');
  }
jQuery(this).addClass('flipped');
}

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost right. Problem is you remove it and then add it back on click.

```
jQuery('.card.effect__click').removeClass('flipped'); //this removes the class
var c = this.classList;
c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped"); //this adds it back
```

**Try this**

```
var alreadyFlipped = $(this).hasClass('flipped');
jQuery('.item').removeClass('flipped'); //flip back all
if (!alreadyFlipped){
    $(this).addClass('flipped'); //flip this one if it needs to
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q4u1dgno/3/)

Comment: That is because I want it to be removed when I click another product. What would be the correct code?

Comment: Do you have any Codepen link? It's not working at all. No divs are flipped.

Comment: Blah, had typo. Update + fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, you can achieve the same effect a bit simpler like this:

```
$(".card.effect__click").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("flipped")) $(this).removeClass("flipped")
    else $(this).addClass("flipped").siblings().removeClass("flipped")
})
```

`$.click` is jQuery's equivalent to a click listener and `$.siblings()` returns the other divs inside the same container. The functions can be chained together because many jQuery functions return the element it was called on.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/q4u1dgno/1/)

Comment: That is a neat solution, however siblings() may have weird behavior and might not work if more classes / scenarios are added in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the code above. I have to stick with the original structure. Is it possible to achieve this with the code I pasted?

Comment: @Stoyan Dekov could you provide an example? I have not heard of that before. You could work around that by first removing the `flipped` class from all the elements inside the container that have it and then add it to the click events target.

Comment: @dominotrix Soyan Dekov's answer should work for you in that case.

Comment: If you take a look at his code, the questionable divs are not siblings but rather cousins as they each have a parent (<article />). My point was this is highly dependable on the DOM structure and very easy to cause regression issues.

Comment: Although it works when I add it alone on Codepen, It doesn't work when I implement it in the website. It partially works.

Check here: http://ananiadis.com.gr/index2.php/pick-me/